# JQuery append function for buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

i want to use JQuery append function to append a button after a button.plz help

```
var button = $("<button>Hi there</button>");
button.click(function() {
    alert("Hi back!");
});
button.appendTo("#tablecell");
```

the above code is used to append a button after some text in a table.but i want to append button after a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var button = $("<button>Hi there</button>");
$("#tablecell").on('click', button, function() {
    alert("Hi back!");
});
button.insertAfter("#tablecell");
```

or

```
 $('#tablecell').insertAfter(button);
```

---

#### Why You need `.on()` delegate

Because your button, append to DOM after page load that means after DOM ready. So ordinary binding will not work there and you need delegate (aka, live) event handler.

```
$(target).on(eventName, handlerFunction) // for ordinary binding
```

but

```
$(container).on(eventName, target, handler) // for delegate binding
```

you've another option `.delegate()` which looks:

```
$(container).delegate(target, eventName, handlerFunction);
```

Comment: +1 for .on(). It drives people (and me) crazy when they hook events on DOM elements before they are ready

Comment: i gave an e.g code of table there...i don't need to insert it after table..the point is that i have a button in html...

<div 
id=":ne" class="T-I J-J5-Ji ar7 nf T-I-ax7 L3" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" style="-webkit-user-select: none; " aria-haspopup="true">
<span class="Ykrj7b">More</span>
</div>

now i want to append a button after this button...nothing more